# Get System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException when I apply the Style on my User Control

Tags: windows-phone-7

I created a user control which applied the Style. After I applied the Style, the design view shows the error message "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException". However, the application can run.  Will it be a problem if I let this error on the page? How can I solve it?

There is the code on my user control:

```
<Button x: Name=btnDescription1"    Click="btnDescription1_Click"  Grid.Row="0"   
      Grid.Column="1"     Style="{StaticResource btnDescription }"  />
```

The code on myApp.xmal:

```
 <Style x:Key="btnDescription" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate>   
                    <StackPanel>       
                          <TextBlock  Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>    
                    </StackPanel>                                         

         </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the target type of your control template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
```